# How to describe the type of props when they are partially used in the React component

Tags: reactjs, typescript

My React component gets props and uses the from part. And also throws them further into another child component

```
<MyComponent prop1="string" prop2="string" prop3="string" prop4="string" /> [3]

type PropsType = {
prop1: string;
prop2: string;
prop3: string; [1]
prop4: string;[2]
}

function MyComponent(props: PropsType) {
const{prop1, prop2} = props;
return(
  <ChildComponent {...props}>
 )
}

type ChildComponentPropTypes = {
prop3: string;
prop4: string;
}

function ChildComponent(props: ChildComponentPropTypes){
const {prop3, prop4} = props;
return(something)
}
```

I get a typescript error:
'props3, props4' PropType is defined but prop is never usedeslintreact/no-unused-prop-types
Please tell me how to get rid of this error

Perhaps you can decide to change the architecture of the code to solve the problem. But I would not like to do that.

if [1] and [2] are omitted, we get an error in [3]: The "prop3, prop4" property does not exist in the "IntrinsicAttributes & PropsType" type

Comment: This ain't throwing any error on my machine. Please provide more context and code samples.

Comment: Himura Da Battosai thanks for the comment. It wasn't a mistake. This is an ESLint warning

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is your eslint [react/no-unused-prop-types](https://github.com/jsx-eslint/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/docs/rules/no-unused-prop-types.md) rule producing the error, not Typescript. Try disabling the rule in your eslint config or adding a `eslint-disable-next-line` comment.

```
function MyComponent(props: PropsType) {
  const{prop1, prop2} = props;
  return(
    // eslint-disable-next-line react/no-unused-prop-types
    <ChildComponent {...props}>
  )
}
```